# Why is networkd changing the MAC addresses of my bonded interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, bonding, mac-address, systemd-networkd

When I add the config files below into `/etc/systemd/network` and restart `systemd-networkd`, I find that the MAC addresses of `bond0`, `eth0` and `eth2` have all been changed to a single, locally administered address. This breaks DHCP, and doesn't follow the expectation set by the Linux kernel bonding documentation that states that the bond interface will take the MAC address of one of its slaves.

According to the networkd documentation, the issue appears to be this:

> **MACAddress=**
>
> The MAC address to use for the device. For "tun" or "tap" devices, setting MACAddress= in the "[NetDev]" section is not supported. Please specify it in "[Link]" section of the corresponding systemd.network(5) file. If this option is not set, "vlan" devices inherit the MAC address of the physical interface. **For other kind of netdevs, if this option is not set, then MAC address is generated based on the interface name and the machine-id(5).**

(Emphasis mine.)

How do I prevent this MAC address generation and tell networkd to just use one from the slaves?

## Files

**10-bond0.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=bond0
Kind=bond

[Bond]
Mode=802.3ad
```

**10-bond0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=bond0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
```

**20-eth0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

**20-eth2.network**

```
[Match]
Name=eth2

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I prevent this MAC address generation and tell networkd to just use one from the slaves?

As far as I know this is not possible. In my project I do set it up using another script. According to [Debian Systemd docu](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemdNetworkd) Systemd-networkd may assign different MAC then the one of physical interface.
You can fix it manually adding MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

I know you didn't mention the OS, but still, your symptoms fit to the Debian...

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample interface and bond file config, `MACADDR` may solve your issue.

#Redhat/Centos

```
#  cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1
DEVICE=eno1
NAME=eno1
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no

# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno2
DEVICE=eno2
NAME=eno2
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no

# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0
DEVICE=bond0
NAME=bond0
TYPE=Bond
MACADDR=a0:36:9f:0f:b1:70         #Assigning fixed mac address
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BONDING_OPTS="mode=active-backup primary=eno1 miimon=100"
```

Or for Ubuntu

#eth0 interace file

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary eth0
```

#eth1 interace file

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0
```

#bond file

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
hwaddress ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx         #fixed mac address
address x.x.x.x                           #Your can remove these lines if it's dhcp
netmask x.x.x.x
gateway x.x.x.x
bond-mode active-backup
bond-miimon 100
bond-slaves none
```

Comment: If this were my home PC's I'd be OK with putting a fixed mac address in there, and this works fine, FWIW - works with netplan too.  But for the kind of deployments I'm working on this is not the world's best plan.  Just about as bad as putting a static arp entry on the switch its attached to.   I was hoping for some explanation of the more esoteric options in the netdev stuff